# Python Persistent HTTP web proxy

Tags: python, proxy

My client initially communicates using persistent HTTP with my own server. I am now trying to insert a web proxy in between them, so ideally the proxy will maintain 2 seperate persistent connections, one with the client and one with the server. How can I create a python web proxy that does that? I've only been able to create a non-persistent one so far, how would I expand it to do persistent connections?

Code so far:

```
def main():
    # host and port info.
    host = ''               # blank for localhost
    port = 80 

    try:
        # create a socket
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # associate the socket to host and port
        s.bind((host, port))

        # listenning
        s.listen(BACKLOG)

    except socket.error, (value, message):
        if s:
            s.close()
        print "Could not open socket:", message
        sys.exit(1)

    # get the connection from client
    while 1:
        print "Proxy running..."
        conn, client_addr_port = s.accept()
        # create a thread to handle request
        thread.start_new_thread(proxy_thread, (conn, client_addr_port))
    s.close()


def proxy_thread(conn, client_addr_port):
    print "received something...creating new thread"    
    global threadcount

    client_addr = client_addr_port[0]
    client_port = client_addr_port[1]

    # Check if this is an new video flow (assumption now is that 1 client has 1 video flow, and the video does not terminate)
    if client_addr not in client_vid_flows:
        print "New client detected", client_addr
        client_vid_flows[client_addr] = 0  # Expand to save video rate
        # ctrl_msg_timer(client_addr)        # Start timer that sends a ctrl_msg to the switch at a certain frequency

    with lock:
        threadcount = threadcount + 1
    print "Thread number:", threadcount

    # get the request from browser
    request_text = conn.recv(MAX_DATA_RECV)

    request = HTTPRequest(request_text)

    if not request:
        sys.exit(1)

    if request.error_code:
        sys.exit(1)

    host = request.headers['host']

    port_pos = host.find(":")           # find the port pos (if any)
    if (port_pos==-1):      # default port
        webserver = host
        port = 80
    else:       # specific port
        webserver = host.split(":")[0]
        port = host.split(":")[1]

    print "Connect to: %s:%i" % (webserver, port)

    try:
        # create a socket to connect to the web server
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
        s.connect((webserver, port))

        s.send(request_text)         # send request to webserver

        while 1:
            # receive data from web server
            data = s.recv(MAX_DATA_RECV)
            print data

            if (len(data) > 0):
                # send to browser
                conn.send(data)
                print 'more to send, len(data)={}'.format(len(data))

            else:
                print 'end of send'

        # s.close()
        # conn.close()
    except socket.error, (value, message):
        if s:
            s.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()
        print "Runtime Error:", message
        sys.exit(1)

    print "--------------------------------"
#********** END PROXY_THREAD ***********

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

From wireshark, I see that a request packet is being sent to the proxy. However, the proxy is not picking this up.

Comment: can you please show your progress?

Comment: have updated the post with my code, thanks